# ValueError: Field 'id' expected a number but got 'john.smith@gmail.com'

Tags: python, django, sqlite, authentication, django-models

I am trying to create custom user model for authentication. I did everything as in Django documentation but when I am trying to create super user with command line, I get the error. I tried to delete database and migrations and run them again, did not help.

**Here is my model.py**

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import AbstractBaseUser, PermissionsMixin, BaseUserManager
from django.db.models.deletion import CASCADE
from django.utils import timezone
from django.utils.translation import gettext_lazy
# Create your models here.

class UserAccountManager(BaseUserManager):
    def create_user(self, Email, Name, Surname, Password = None, **other_fields):
        
        if not Email:
            raise ValueError(gettext_lazy('You must provide email address'))

        email = self.normalize_email(Email)
        user = self.model(email, Name, Surname, **other_fields)
        user.set_password(Password)
        user.save(using=self._db)
       
        return user

    def create_superuser(self, Email, Name, Surname, Password = None, **other_fields):
        
        other_fields.setdefault('is_staff', True)
        other_fields.setdefault('is_superuser', True)
        other_fields.setdefault('is_active', True)
        return self.create_user(Email=Email, Name = Name, Surname = Surname, Password = Password, **other_fields)

class Customer(AbstractBaseUser, PermissionsMixin):
    Email = models.EmailField(gettext_lazy('email address'), max_length=256, unique=True)
    Name = models.CharField(max_length=64)
    Surname = models.CharField(max_length=64, null=True)
    Birthday = models.DateField(auto_now=False, null=False,blank=True)
    PhoneNumber = models.CharField(max_length=16, unique=True, blank=True)
    Address = models.CharField(max_length=128, blank=True)
    RegistrationDate  = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now, editable=False)
    is_staff = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    is_active = models.BooleanField(default=True)
    is_superuser = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    objects = UserAccountManager()
    USERNAME_FIELD = 'Email'
    REQUIRED_FIELDS = ['Name', 'Surname']

    def __str__(self):
        return self.Name + " " + self.Surname

    def has_perm(self, perm, obj = None):
        return self.is_superuser
```

**Here is my admin.py**

```
from django import forms
from django.contrib import admin
from django.contrib.auth.admin import UserAdmin as BaseUserAdmin
from django.contrib.auth.forms import ReadOnlyPasswordHashField
from django.core.exceptions import ValidationError

from .models import *
# Register your models here.

class UserCreationForm(forms.ModelForm):

    password1 = forms.CharField(label='Password', widget=forms.PasswordInput)
    password2 = forms.CharField(label='Password confirmation', widget=forms.PasswordInput)

    class Meta:
        model = Customer
        fields = ('Email', 'Name', 'Surname')
    def clean_password2(self):
        password1 = self.cleaned_data.get("password1")
        password2 = self.cleaned_data.get("password2")
        if password1 and password2 and password1 != password2:
            raise ValidationError("Passwords don't match")
        return password2

    def save(self, commit=True):
        # Save the provided password in hashed format
        user = super().save(commit=False)
        user.set_password(self.cleaned_data["password1"])
        if commit:
            user.save()
        return user


class UserChangeForm(forms.ModelForm):

    password = ReadOnlyPasswordHashField()

    class Meta:
        model = Customer
        fields = ('Email', 'Name','Surname','Birthday','PhoneNumber','Address', 'is_staff', 'is_active', 'is_superuser')
    def clean_password(self):

        return self.initial["password"]

class UserAdmin(BaseUserAdmin):
    form = UserChangeForm
    add_form = UserCreationForm


    list_display = ('Email', 'Name', 'Surname')
    list_filter = ('is_superuser','Email', 'Name', 'Birthday')
    fieldsets = (
        (None, {'fields': ('Email', 'password')}),
        ('Personal info', {'fields': ('Birthday','Name','Surname')}),
        ('Permissions', {'fields': ('is_superuser',)}),
    )

    add_fieldsets = ()
    search_fields = ('Email',)
    ordering = ('Email',)
    filter_horizontal = ()

      
admin.site.register(Customer,UserAdmin)
```

**Here is the traceback of the error**

```
 File "C:\Users\asus\Desktop\Django_projects\Delivery_Website\deliveryvenv\lib\site-packages\django\db\m
odels\fields\__init__.py", line 1774, in get_prep_value
    return int(value)
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: 'john.smith@gmail.com'

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "manage.py", line 22, in <module>
    main()
  File "manage.py", line 18, in main
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "C:\Users\asus\Desktop\Django_projects\Delivery_Website\deliveryvenv\lib\site-packages\django\core
\management\__init__.py", line 401, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "C:\Users\asus\Desktop\Django_projects\Delivery_Website\deliveryvenv\lib\site-packages\django\core
\management\__init__.py", line 395, in execute
    self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
  File "C:\Users\asus\Desktop\Django_projects\Delivery_Website\deliveryvenv\lib\site-packages\django\core
\management\base.py", line 330, in run_from_argv
    self.execute(*args, **cmd_options)
  File "C:\Users\asus\Desktop\Django_projects\Delivery_Website\deliveryvenv\lib\site-packages\django\cont
rib\auth\management\commands\createsuperuser.py", line 79, in execute
    return super().execute(*args, **options)
  File "C:\Users\asus\Desktop\Django_projects\Delivery_Website\deliveryvenv\lib\site-packages\django\core
\management\base.py", line 371, in execute
    output = self.handle(*args, **options)
  File "C:\Users\asus\Desktop\Django_projects\Delivery_Website\deliveryvenv\lib\site-packages\django\cont
rib\auth\management\commands\createsuperuser.py", line 189, in handle
    self.UserModel._default_manager.db_manager(database).create_superuser(**user_data)
  File "C:\Users\asus\Desktop\Django_projects\Delivery_Website\delivery-project\deliveryapp\models.py", l
ine 26, in create_superuser
    return self.create_user(Email=Email, Name = Name, Surname = Surname, Password = Password, **other_fie
lds)
  File "C:\Users\asus\Desktop\Django_projects\Delivery_Website\delivery-project\deliveryapp\models.py", l
ine 17, in create_user
    user.save(using=self._db)
  File "C:\Users\asus\Desktop\Django_projects\Delivery_Website\deliveryvenv\lib\site-packages\django\cont
rib\auth\base_user.py", line 67, in save
    super().save(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\asus\Desktop\Django_projects\Delivery_Website\deliveryvenv\lib\site-packages\django\db\m
odels\base.py", line 753, in save
    self.save_base(using=using, force_insert=force_insert,
  File "C:\Users\asus\Desktop\Django_projects\Delivery_Website\deliveryvenv\lib\site-packages\django\db\m
odels\base.py", line 790, in save_base
    updated = self._save_table(
  File "C:\Users\asus\Desktop\Django_projects\Delivery_Website\deliveryvenv\lib\site-packages\django\db\m
odels\base.py", line 872, in _save_table
    updated = self._do_update(base_qs, using, pk_val, values, update_fields,
  File "C:\Users\asus\Desktop\Django_projects\Delivery_Website\deliveryvenv\lib\site-packages\django\db\m
odels\base.py", line 906, in _do_update
    filtered = base_qs.filter(pk=pk_val)
  File "C:\Users\asus\Desktop\Django_projects\Delivery_Website\deliveryvenv\lib\site-packages\django\db\m
odels\query.py", line 942, in filter
    return self._filter_or_exclude(False, *args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\asus\Desktop\Django_projects\Delivery_Website\deliveryvenv\lib\site-packages\django\db\m
odels\query.py", line 962, in _filter_or_exclude
    clone._filter_or_exclude_inplace(negate, *args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\asus\Desktop\Django_projects\Delivery_Website\deliveryvenv\lib\site-packages\django\db\m
odels\query.py", line 969, in _filter_or_exclude_inplace
    self._query.add_q(Q(*args, **kwargs))
  File "C:\Users\asus\Desktop\Django_projects\Delivery_Website\deliveryvenv\lib\site-packages\django\db\m
odels\sql\query.py", line 1358, in add_q
    clause, _ = self._add_q(q_object, self.used_aliases)
  File "C:\Users\asus\Desktop\Django_projects\Delivery_Website\deliveryvenv\lib\site-packages\django\db\m
odels\sql\query.py", line 1377, in _add_q
    child_clause, needed_inner = self.build_filter(
  File "C:\Users\asus\Desktop\Django_projects\Delivery_Website\deliveryvenv\lib\site-packages\django\db\m
odels\sql\query.py", line 1319, in build_filter
    condition = self.build_lookup(lookups, col, value)
  File "C:\Users\asus\Desktop\Django_projects\Delivery_Website\deliveryvenv\lib\site-packages\django\db\m
odels\sql\query.py", line 1165, in build_lookup
    lookup = lookup_class(lhs, rhs)
  File "C:\Users\asus\Desktop\Django_projects\Delivery_Website\deliveryvenv\lib\site-packages\django\db\m
odels\lookups.py", line 24, in __init__
    self.rhs = self.get_prep_lookup()
  File "C:\Users\asus\Desktop\Django_projects\Delivery_Website\deliveryvenv\lib\site-packages\django\db\m
odels\lookups.py", line 76, in get_prep_lookup
    return self.lhs.output_field.get_prep_value(self.rhs)
  File "C:\Users\asus\Desktop\Django_projects\Delivery_Website\deliveryvenv\lib\site-packages\django\db\m
odels\fields\__init__.py", line 1776, in get_prep_value
    raise e.__class__(
ValueError: Field 'id' expected a number but got 'john.smith@gmail.com'.
```

Comment: You write `self.model(email, Name, Surname, **other_fields)` passing email, Name and Surname as **positional arguments**. Instead pass them as **keyword arguments**.

Comment: @AbdulAzizBarkat thank you, It works now!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your `create_user` method you write `self.model(email, Name, Surname, **other_fields)`, here you pass `email`, `Name` and `Surname` as positional arguments, which is the reason you get an error (basically the email is taken as the id field and the arguments you pass actually go to some other fields or so). Instead pass these as keyword arguments. So your `create_user` method would be:

```py
def create_user(self, Email, Name, Surname, Password = None, **other_fields):
    # Your other code
    user = self.model(Email=email, Name=Name, Surname=Surname, **other_fields)
    # Your other code
```

> **Note**: According to convention variable names in python should be in `snake_case`. So it should be `email` instead of <s>`Email`</s>,
> etc. See [PEP 8 -- Style Guide for Python
> Code](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/)